# Basic Code::Blocks problem

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I apologize for asking a question of this caliber. I am at my wits end and have spent to much time trying to figure out how to get the side bar I closed back. I closed the "management" (the box with all the headers and .cpp's) and "messages" (where the compiler errors are displayed) box after I created a project. Now I can't get them back. When I close and reopen the management box is back, but the compiler box is not. I looked through the tabs for a while and will continue to investigate, but I think this is a really simple problem I have made extremely hard.

-With thanks and regret.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the config file? Or try "codeblocks.exe --clear-configuration" in the command line

Comment: For general reference - I think the OP is referring to [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), a free C++ IDE.

Comment: Yes, Code::Blocks sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Do you mean the "Build log" by compiler box?

Comment: Yes, the build log is one of the tabs in the messages box. The tabs are located at the bottom of the box. The other tabs are: Code::Blocks Debug, Search Result, Build Log, Build Messages, Debugger, there may be more.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on one of the tabs that are showing up in the "Logs & others" pane. Then you should be able to re-enable other tabs in the "Toggle..." menu.

[image: Logs & others pane]

If you don't see any tabs, just right-click in the pane.

Comment: @user492440: If that worked for you, you should accept the answer as correct.

Comment: +1 upvote for @AndiDog 's answer. Just what is it with people not properly marking the answer as accept if it, in fact, solved the issue for them?

Comment: @Victor: In this case, the reason is that the user just doesn't use SO anymore (last visit says "Oct 31").